# upload image to folder using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I want to browse image & upload it to folder using python. I have tried a variety of solutions posted on on the forum but none of them worked in my case. Please guide me on what needs to be corrected. Thanks all for your quick help.

I'm getting error

raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: has_key

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

import cgi
import datetime
import webapp2
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import users

guestbook_key = ndb.Key('Guestbook', 'default_guestbook')

class Greeting(ndb.Model):
  author = ndb.UserProperty()
  content = ndb.TextProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')

    greetings = ndb.gql('SELECT * '
                        'FROM Greeting '
                        'WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 '
                        'ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10',
                        guestbook_key)

    for greeting in greetings:
      if greeting.author:
        self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
      else:
        self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
      self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                              cgi.escape(greeting.content))


    self.response.out.write("""
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/sign" method="post">
<p>File: <input type="file" name="file1"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
      </html>""")


class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
    #file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', max_length=5234,blank=True, null=True,)
    # docfile = forms.FileField(label='', show_hidden_initial='none',required=True,)



    fileitem = str(self.request.get('file1'))

# Test if the file was uploaded
    if self.request.has_key('file1'):

   # strip leading path from file name to avoid directory traversal attacks
       fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.file)
       open('files/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
       message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

    else:
       message = 'No file was uploaded'

    print """\
    Content-Type: text/html\n
    <html><body>
    <p>%s</p>
    </body></html>
    """ % (message,)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/sign', Guestbook)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop here and go back and read the introductory documentation on appengine and the python runtime. If you read through the intro docs you will see the section on the python runtime and the sandbox and it's restrictions.

On examining that section of documentation you will see you can not write to the filesystem in appengine. It is also worth noting the other restrictions whilst you are at it.

As to where in the code your error is, you should at least include a stacktrace and look at the particular lines of code where the error occurs and then ask specific questions about that rather than dump all of your code and saying what error you got.

At the moment I don't see a lot of point looking at the problem in your code where the `has_key` error occurs, that error is self explanatory  and the rest of what you are trying to do just won't work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your GAE Python project files are read only. You can only change those files when you update your project using appcfg.py or push-to-deploy.

But you can use Google cloudstorage folders or subdirectories to upload, write or overwrite files.
Docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

If you use the appid default bucket for your folders, you have 5 GB of free quota.